# R - Shading part of a ggplot2 histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I have this data:

```
dataset     = rbinom(1000, 16, 0.5)
mean        = mean(dataset)
sd          = sd(dataset)
data_subset = subset(dataset, dataset >= (mean - 2*sd) & dataset <= (mean + 2*sd))

dataset     = data.frame(X=dataset)
data_subset = data.frame(X=data_subset)
```

And here's how I'm drawing my histogram for `dataset`:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = X)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") +
   theme_bw()
```

[image: dataset]

How can I shade the `data_subset` portion of the histogram, like so?

[image: data_subset]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution is very similar to joran's -- I think they're both worth looking at for the slight differences:

```
ggplot(dataset,aes(x=X)) +
   geom_histogram(binwidth=1,fill="white",color="black") +
   geom_histogram(data=subset(dataset,X>6&X<10),binwidth=1, 
   colour="black", fill="grey")+theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Accepting joran's answer because he was first.. I wish I could accept both, sorry!

Comment: No problem (but you should use my code. :-)  The aes inherit and you don't need a separate dataframe when you can subset within the ggplot)

Answer (score 2):

Just add another `geom_histogram` line using that data subset (although you may have to tinker with the binwidth a bit, I'm not sure):

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = X)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white") + 
   geom_histogram(data = data_subset,aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, colour="black",fill = "grey") +
   theme_bw()
```