# Histogram conditional fill color

Tags: r, if-statement, colors, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to make a histogram where the fill color changes depending on the low end of the bin.  I do not want a [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016316/how-to-manually-fill-colors-in-a-ggplot2-histogram) fill.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869498/applying-scale-fill-gradient-in-ggplot2-conditionally) seems promising, but I could not transition it successfully to a histogram and two-value (not gradient) color scheme.  I believe the solution may be some `ifelse` logic within `geom_histogram(fill= )` but I don't know how to access the bin starting value.

For example, in the below histogram, I would like to color revenue bins over $100,000 red to show the high-revenue customers.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

n <- 10000
cust <- data.frame(cust_id=1:n,cust_rev <- rexp(n,.00001))

# I want to use a log scale for my tick marks and bin breaks
powers <- function(base,exp) sapply(1:exp, function(exp) base^exp )

ggplot(cust, aes(cust_rev)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="black",fill="light blue", binwidth=1/3) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels=comma, breaks=powers(10,8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
  xlab("Customer Revenue") + ylab("Number of Customers") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Customer Value")
```

[image]

Also, I attempted a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337811/r-shading-part-of-a-ggplot2-histogram) with a second geom_histogram(), but was unsuccessful.

```
ggplot(cust, aes(x=cust_rev)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="black",fill="light blue", binwidth=1/3) + 
  geom_histogram(data=subset(cust,cust_rev>100000),
                 color="black",fill="red", binwidth=1/3) + 
  scale_x_log10(labels=comma, breaks=powers(10,8)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
  xlab("Customer Revenue ($)") + ylab("Number of Customers") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Customer Value")
# Error in data.frame(x = c(45291.1377418786, 52770.7004919648, 15748.975193128,
#   : arguments imply differing number of rows: 10000, 3568
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be easiest to just add another column with the condition and update the `aes` to include the fill group.

```
cust$high_rev <- as.factor((cust[,2]>100000)*1)

ggplot(cust, aes(cust_rev, fill=high_rev)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="black", binwidth=1/3) + 
    scale_x_log10(labels=comma, breaks=powers(10,8)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
    xlab("Customer Revenue") + ylab("Number of Customers") +
    ggtitle("Distribution of Customer Value")
```

[image]

If you have your heart set on some specific colors you can use the `scale_fill_manual` function.  Here is an example with some fun bright colors.

```
ggplot(cust, aes(cust_rev, fill=high_rev)) + 
    geom_histogram(color="black", binwidth=1/3) + 
    scale_x_log10(labels=comma, breaks=powers(10,8)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels=comma) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "purple")) +
    xlab("Customer Revenue") + ylab("Number of Customers") +
    ggtitle("Distribution of Customer Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted for use of `scale_fill_manual()`.  However, as ziggystar (+1) suggested below, I skipped adding a column to the df and directly passed the condition to the aes(fill= )).  Also, I added `guides(fill=FALSE)` to the plot to suppress the legend.

Answer (score 4):

How about this one?

```
ggplot(cust, aes(cust_rev)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=cust_rev > 100000),binwidth=1/3) + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

or equivalently

```
ggplot(cust, aes(x=cust_rev,fill=cust_rev > 100000)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1/3) + 
  scale_x_log10()
```

Comment: Although for this example IMO more concise and better option than the accepted answer, this would not allow for filling by multiple conditions... the accepted answer would allow for that... or am I overlooking something?

Comment: If you can construct some expression that returns different values  (e.g. using switch or cut), you can do it. But then it would become a bit messy, and I'd suggest adding a column.